# CSS input[type="submit"][disabled] is not working in Firefox

Tags: css

I tried

```
input[type="button"][disabled="disabled"]{  
      color:gray !important;  
}
```

this CSS in my code its working in IE but not in Firefox.

Is this css won't work for Firefox..??

My HTML code

```
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit"></input>  
<script location="body">
document.getElementById("submit").disabled=true;
</script>
```

Please help me..

Comment: The markup in your title and question are different. Do you have a jsfiddle containing the relevant markup and styles?

Comment: why `[disabled="disabled"]` rather than just `[disabled]` ?

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/cLbJy/

Comment: Share your html code.

Comment: @StuperUser Whatever selector he uses, both are correct

Comment: @emilan Please find the HTML code.

Comment: Pls see my answer below, I write some small example, you need to add disabled attribute for input element.

Comment: So if disable the button through javascript, this css wont work..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some code snippet: Will help you to understand the omission you did.

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            input[type="button"][disabled="disabled"]{
                color:gray !important;
            }
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function myFunc() {
                document.getElementById("myButton").disabled = true;
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="myFunc()">
        <input id="myButton" type="button" value="Hello"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank u so much for the response but, Is that necessary to add disabled attribute in html..?? I am disabling the button through javascript..

Comment: I did changes, pls review one more time

Comment: Actually mine xml rendering html code because of that its not working i think so. :-(

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
input[type="button"][disabled]{
    color:gray
}
```

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/5DXuM/)**.